# FlowType: null check fails

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Why does the null-check fail in `func1` while it is ok in `func2`

```
/* @flow */

const func1 = (arr?: Array<*>) => {
  const isArrayNotEmpty = arr && arr.length;

  if (isArrayNotEmpty) {
    arr.forEach((element) => console.log(element));
  }
}

const func2 = (arr?: Array<*>) => {
  if (arr && arr.length) {
    arr.forEach((element) => console.log(element));
  }
}
```

[Live example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzCgFdsMBGMAXjAAoBDAJ0YH4AuMAQWfoE8AeEAD4AlNSFgA3qjBgseQgEtc3RnwBycfAFEAtgAd8vamCaMwAMgunmAOhgBTbAHN8ACwDcMsN8VQ6yqoaWnqGvGLSsrJmtlBwjNr0GG60tA6Ouk74YlQS8rhwjvZwzmkZWSIiXrIAvqh1mDgERKQYAEwmDMzsXDwCwjkSkWB+dGaW1jGOLu4R3tF2cQlJKWUOmdjZ4nJNhQ7FpenrFVXedTVAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the reasons why Flow doesn't support this, but it doesn't. It currently requires that checks for type refinements actually happen in the `if` statement, and does not track them if they are abstracted out into a separate variable.

There is an alternative that may be acceptable to you (I'm not sure it's documented anywhere):

```
/* @flow */

const func1 = (arr?: Array<*>) => {
  if (isArrayNotEmpty(arr)) {
    arr.forEach((element) => console.log(element));
  }
}

function isArrayNotEmpty(x: mixed): %checks {
  return x && x.length;
}
```

([tryflow](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzCgFdsMBGMAXjAAoBDAJ0YH4AuMAQWfoE8AeEAD4AlNSFgA3qjBgAllDpzc3RnwBycfAFEAtgAd8vBsxFjps2U0YA6KHEbb6GABa1aAUxgfdH7PjEqCSw8OG8beABzT29ffzMAbhkwAF9UNNQSMnw5HHkVHl5NHQMjWgAPDl05co8AExEOAFJXDwwAa1wpZMYPfGJGbDBysAAyUeGIv0j8FySUoA))

The special `%checks` return type indicates to Flow that it should look into the body of the function to figure out what it implies about the types of the variables it is passed. I believe there are some restrictions on what can be in the body of such a function. It may even be the case that it just has to return a single expression. This should give you enough to experiment with it, though.